# Is it ok to use count + 1 in ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, ternary

What I want to do is check if there is element in array, if it is, I want to increment counter. Compiler reports error when I do count++ but not when I do count + 1, and it increments correctly. Is it because count++ is operation and not an expression, and count + 1 is expression?

```
let count = 0;

//not working
count = checkArr(arr) ? count++ : count;

//working
count = checkArr(arr) ? count + 1 : count;
```

Comment: If it works, I don't see why it's not okay to use :p

Comment: Postfix `++` first returns an old value and then increments the value itself. If you'd change it to prefix one (such as `++count`) it'll work. However it is not necessary to modufy count in ternary operator, because you assignign to it as a result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is forbidden, but some good practice can be adopted.

Mixing up assignation `count =`, conditioning `?:` and post incrementation `++` is a lot inside of a same line.

Always go for the simpliest solution when coding something. In your case :

```
if (checkArr(arr)) {
  count += 1;
}
```

is way easier to understand than a ternary which does not seems to be appropriate in that particular context.

---

There are existing tool auditing code quality, as sonarqube, eslint ...

They are always requiring simplicity.

**Example about ternary rules :**

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-ternary
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary

**Example about post/pre incrementation :**

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus

They want coder to avoid the use of ++/-- because for some people it can be misleading. A lot of people do not know the difference between `++var` and `var++` which may led to bugs. Prefer `var += 1;`.

Answer (score 3):

Use prefix operator. It's because with postfix, value is incremented after its first read.  With prefix you will get updated `count` value before it read.

```
count = checkArr(arr) ? ++count : count;
```

Should work

Comment: It would work, but it's a really odd construction. First you are incrementing the variable and then overwriting it with the same value. It would be way better off without the ternary IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal to use ternary operator like this. However I would argue about code style here.

```
count = checkArr(arr) ? count + 1 : count;
```

In this line expressionFalse part (after :) is completely useless and doesn't do anything and it's there only to make ternary operator syntax correct.

For this case IMO following construction is more readable:

```
if (checkArr(arr)) {
    ++count;
}
```

or

```
if (checkArr(arr)) ++count;
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of `count++` and `++count` is different.

In short:

`count = count++` : The value of `count++` is the value *BEFORE* the increment.

`count = ++count` : The value of `++count` is the value *AFTER* the increment.

```
let count = 5;
console.log(count++); //return 5
console.log(count); //return 6

let count = 10;
console.log(++count); //return 11
console.log(count); //return 11
```

This works the same for `count--` and `--count`

However, one thing to note here is in eslint this would be considered error, and it's recommended to use `+=1` instead.

Link fyi: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus